# How do I access the local filesystem from a Python Docker image?

Tags: python, image, docker, filesystems

This might have an answer elsewhere but I could not find it. 
I have a Docker image for Python 3.x:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              latest              26acbad26a2c        2 months ago        690MB
```

I run the image using this command:

```
$ docker run -i -t python
```

However, from inside the Docker container I want to be able to access my local filesystem to import Python modules etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The docker container's filesytem is isolated from the host's filesystem. Thus by default you cannot access files on the host unless you mount the directory onto the container.

To do that, you need to use a [bindmount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) to mount the host directory onto the container:

```
docker run -it --volume <host-folder-path>:<container-folder-path> python
```

Now, Inside the container you will have the host folder accessible under "*container-folder-path*"

Answer (score 0):

you have to mount your local folder into container to

docker run -v /host/folder:/container/folder-i -t python