# Read .accdb database in Python app running on Docker container (Alpine)

Tags: python, docker, ms-access, alpine-linux, mdbtools

I am trying and failing to read a local .accdb file in my Python 3.11 app, which is running in an `python:3.11-alpine` container.

My Dockerfile executes without errors:

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-alpine

EXPOSE 5001
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc g++ musl-dev unixodbc-dev flex bison gawk
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk add --no-cache git autoconf automake libtool gettext-dev make
RUN git clone https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools.git
WORKDIR /mdbtools
RUN autoreconf -i -f
RUN ./configure --with-unixodbc=/usr --disable-dependency-tracking
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN echo -e "\n[MDBTools]\nDescription=MDBTools Driver\nDriver=/usr/local/lib/odbc/libmdbodbc.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN apk add --no-cache nano

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

My Python script (`accdb_test.py`):

```
import pyodbc
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Connect to an Access database.')
parser.add_argument('db_path', type=str, help='The path to the Access database')

args = parser.parse_args()

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={MDBTools};'
    r'DBQ=' + args.db_path + ';'
)
try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    print("Connection successful!")
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Failed to connect to the database:", e)
```

I build the container connect to its terminal, than I run the script with this result:

```bash
/app $ python accdb_test.py /app/input_examples/caesar/MODEL_13-16_R01.ACCDB
['MDBTools']
File not found
File not found
Unable to locate database
Failed to connect to the database: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

The path to the `.accdb` file is correct, I checked:

```bash
/app $ ls -l /app/input_examples/caesar/MODEL_13-16_R01.ACCDB
-rwxrwxrwx    1 appuser  root      47116288 Mar 18 09:29 /app/input_examples/caesar/MODEL_13-16_R01.ACCDB
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464614/how-do-i-access-the-local-filesystem-from-a-python-docker-image#:~:text=The%20docker%20container%27s%20filesytem%20is%20isolated%20from%20the,the%20container%3A%20docker%20run%20-it%20--volume%20%3Chost-folder-path%3E%3A%3Ccontainer-folder-path%3E%20python

Comment: No, the script outputs precisely the same error if executed on file in the mounted volume.

Comment: Could you print `args.db_path`? Just to make sure nothing weird is going on there.

Comment: It prints out: ```/app/input_examples/caesar/MODEL_13-16_R01.ACCDB``` which is correct (see my question for what happens when I run ```ls -l``` with precisely this path).

Comment: @ErikA - My apologies! I just tested with Docker and the trailing semicolon is indeed causing the error. Please undelete your answer.

Comment: @ErikA I didn't catch your answer but removing `;` from line `r'DBQ=' + args.db_path + ';'` indeed fixed my issue . Please undelete your original answer so I can give you the award.

Comment: It's undeleted. Glad the issue is fixed! Odd it appears to be inconsistent across environments, apparently.

Comment: @ErikA Thank you. The odd behavior is a bummer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, mdbtools expects a 2-component connection string, with only a single semicolon.

Since you end your connection string with a semicolon, it is looking for a file named `/app/input_examples/caesar/MODEL_13-16_R01.ACCDB;` and cannot find that file.

This can be seen [here](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools/blob/7e057e3197604fafa58e622ec2d42f407dd3b8bc/src/odbc/connectparams.c#L264) in the source, it's splitting the connection string into a maximum of 2 components, where any further separators and components get added to the file name.

The fix is simple: remove the semicolon:

```py
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={MDBTools};'
    r'DBQ=' + args.db_path
)
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tested this on Ubuntu 22.04 with odbc-mdbtools 1.0.0+dfsg-1 (from the repos) and `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=MDBTools;DBQ=mdb2000Test.mdb;")` (trailing semicolon) worked for me.

Comment: It fixed my issue. The inconsistent behavior across environments is almost (if not entirely) a bug IMHO. I don't have the time or know-how to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

The way mdbtools is being built in the original Dockerfile causes the `g_strsplit()` function (used [here](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools/blob/7e057e3197604fafa58e622ec2d42f407dd3b8bc/src/odbc/connectparams.c#L264)) to malfunction. The following Dockerfile allows `g_strsplit()` to work correctly and the `.connect()` will not fail when `DBQ=` has a trailing semicolon.

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add \
    build-base \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    glib \
    glib-dev \
    libc-dev \
    libtool \
    bison \
    flex-dev \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    git

RUN python -m pip install pyodbc

RUN git clone https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools.git
WORKDIR /mdbtools
RUN autoreconf -i -f
RUN ./configure --with-unixodbc=/usr --disable-man
RUN make
RUN make install

RUN echo -e "\n[MDBTools]\nDescription=MDBTools Driver\nDriver=/usr/local/lib/odbc/libmdbodbc.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

WORKDIR /app
COPY accdb_test.py accdb_test.py
COPY ansi92test.accdb ansi92test.accdb
```